# Laravel - Retornar HTML ou JSON no mesmo Método

Tags: php, laravel, mvc

Estou iniciando com Laravel, vendo do rails, onde para retornar um JSON faço simplesmente colocar .json na url, obvio que o tratamento de retorno está no Controller.

Minha dúvida é como fazer algo parecido com Laravel. Gostaria de, ao inves de criar um método para retornar html e outro para json, ter apenas um para ambos e na view eu poderia determinar qual seria o retorno.

```
  public function lista(){
    $produtos = 'select na tabela';
    return view('produtos.listagem')->withProdutos($produtos);
  }
```

O Código acima retorna htmlpor padrão, teria como escolher o tipo de retorno?

Abraços

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573457/laravel-5-return-html-or-json-depending-on-route

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minha solução para isso seria detectando o `header` da requisição.

Se for requerido `XHTTPRequest`, retornamos `JSON`. Se não, retornamos `HTML`.

Pense nessa ideia:

```
Route::get('usuarios/listar', function (Request $request)
{

     $usuarios = Usuario::all();


     if ($request->ajax()) {
         response()->json(compact('usuarios'));
     }

     return view('usuarios.listar', compact('usuarios'));
});
```

Assim, se você acessar a url, verá a `view`. Se utilizar um `$.ajax`, irá retornar o `JSON`.

**Atualizaçao**:

Existe um método que, ao meu ver, é melhor que `$request->ajax()`. Esse método se chama `$request->wantsJson()`. Ele basicamente identifica se a requisição enviou um header dizendo que resposta `JSON` é aceita.

Comment: Perfeito!Obrigado